# setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api to return the result which is the nested object. And initially state is as shown below:

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({
     name: null,
     age: null,
     address: {
         city: null,
         zipCode: null
     }
})
```

Once the api gets called and return the result which contains all the properties, we will call setObj. Do we need to call like `setObj({...obj, results})` or we can call `setObj(results)` directly?

Per my unerstanding, state is immutable in react and we cannot modify it directly. Please correct me if I am wrong. a smiliar quesiton I found is [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object returned by the API contains only a subset of the existing properties, such as

```
{
  name: 'foo'
}
```

then you would need to spread the existing object into the new state to retain the old `null` properties.

```
setObj({ ...obj, ...results });
```

You'd also need to factor in deep cloning the `address` if needed - remember that spread only creates a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

If the object returned by the API contains all the properties, then you don't care about anything in the previous object with `null`s, so you'd just need

```
setObj(results);
```

Comment: We should also use the lambda variant rather than `setObj({ ...obj, ...results });` so that it gets updated `obj`

Comment: The function version is only necessary if the scope of this setter is within a stale closure. I wouldn't put it in unless it's necessary, and nothing in the question indicates such a thing, so I'd leave it out.

Comment: The question mentioned fetching data with API, so high probability it will be inside useEffect, so updating the state with lambda is an important point